# UVa 10120 Gift?! in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm learning common lisp I've been given a problem out of the uVA database (http://acm.uva.es/p/v101/10120.html) and a breadth search function (which takes in a start point, goal point and a legal move generator), i've got the theory down as to how i'm meant to get the answer but Lisp just isn't agreeing with me. Can i have some advice on how to proceed from this point onwards? Below is a link to the given problem and my two of my attempted solutions with lisp source code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

1.

```
(defun gift (N G)
(setq CR 9)
(setq i 3)
(cond ((= N G) "N and G equal")
    ((< N G) "Gift it on a rock outside limits")
    ((> N 49) "number of rocks is bigger than 49 - it will work")
    ((< N 9) "number of rocks is less than 9, it wont work")
    ((= N 0) "number of rocks is 0, it wont work")
    ((= G 0) "gift isn't on a rock, it wont work"))
(loop
  (setq I (+ I 1))
  (setq I (-(* I 2) 1))
  (setq CR 9) 
 (breadth-search CR G #'lmg-moves)
(when (= CR G) (return "Let me Try!"))
(when (> CR N) (return "Don't laugh at me!"))
  ))

(defun lmg-moves (I)
(list (+ 9 I)
    (- 9 I)
    ))
```

2.

```
(defvar *currentRock* 9)
(defvar *iterator* 3)

(defun gift (N G)
 (setq *iterator* (+ *iterator* 1))
 ;; (breadth-search *currentRock* G #'LMG)
)

(defun LMG (a)
(+ a (-(* *iterator* 2) 1))
   )
```

As can be seen above, the general idea is to simply apply a breadth-search function with the given legal move generator and hopefully, by analizing it's output we can determine whether we can reach the goal state or not. I will be glad to answer any questions if the code above is too confusing, thanks again!.

Comment: you need to declare variables

Answer (score 2):

Among other potential issues:

You're using LOOP wrong. See [PCL](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html) for info on loop. I've rehacked it a bit, but I don't know what you are attempting.

SETF is recommended over SETQ, as SETF is more general.

INCF increments a place by 1.

Your indentation is bad; if you fixed that you would notice that you're falling off the end of COND into the LOOP. I'd recommend an auto-indenting editor for using Lisp here. (Emacs is the standby).

```
(defun gift (N G)
    (setq CR 9)
    (setq i 3)
    (cond ((= N G) "N and G equal")
          ((< N G) "Gift it on a rock outside limits")
          ((> N 49) "number of rocks is bigger than 49 - it will work")
          ((< N 9) "number of rocks is less than 9, it wont work")
          ((= N 0) "number of rocks is 0, it wont work")
          ((= G 0) "gift isn't on a rock, it wont work")) )
    (loop 
      while t
      do
       (setq I (+ I 1))
       (setq I (-(* I 2) 1))
       (setq CR 9) 
       (breadth-search CR G #'lmg-moves)
       (when (= CR G)
         (return "Let me Try!"))
       (when (> CR N)
         (return "Don't laugh at me!"))))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some things that are immediately obvious:

- You have exactly two legal return values, "Let me try!", and "Don't make fun of me!".  You misspelt the first, rephrased the second, and added a lot of strings that do not have a use for the problem (are they meant as comments?).
- The description calls the variables `N` and `M`, but your attempts take parameters `N` and `G`.  Why confuse yourself?  Either call them `N` and `M`, or (better) use meaningful names, like `rock-number` and `gift-place`.

Now, let's see your program structure.

```
(defun gift (N G)
  (setq CR 9)
  (setq i 3))
```

These `setq` instructions have undefined behaviour at this point, because `CR` and `I` are not defined yet.  Many Lisp implementations will implicitly create globally special variables of these names, but it is bad style to depend on it.  I have the impression that you want to use `let` here, like this:

```
(defun gift (rock-number gift-place)
  (let ((current-rock 0)
        (jump-number 0))
    ;; ...
    ))
```

Note that you should really start from the beginning, because you would miss the solution when the gift is on rock 1 or 4.

Next up, that `cond` form: it is dead code, because it has no side effects, and you throw away its return value immediately.  It is thus at best a comment, and you should use a comment for that.

Finally, we have this funny loop:

```
(loop
  (setq I (+ I 1))
  (setq I (-(* I 2) 1))
  (setq CR 9) 
  (breadth-search CR G #'lmg-moves)
  (when (= CR G) (return "Let me Try!"))
  (when (> CR N) (return "Don't laugh at me!"))))
```

I don't know what `breadth-search` does, but it seems that you really depend on the manipulation of globally special variables.  I cannot say what might happen here.  However, I can see several problems:

- You can have up to two locations when jumping a certain distance from a given rock.  It cannot be right to check only a single variable after each jump.
- You seem to confuse the jump number with its jump distance.  `I` goes in the sequence 1, 3, 7, 15 …, but the jump number sequence would be 1, 2, 3, 4 … while the jump distance sequence would be 1, 3, 5, 7 ….  Even the rocks visited when always jumping right are a different sequence (1, 4, 9, 16 …).
- You reset `CR` to 9 each time through the loop.  I do not see how that could be right.

Stylistically, you should keep your variables as local as possible, using for example `let`, `do`, or the extended `loop` keywords `:for` and `:with`, then pass them into the functions that need them as arguments.  This makes it much easier to reason about what is happening.

I think that your mental model of the solution algorithm is a bit confused.  I would structure this in such a way that you loop over the jumps and keep a set of rocks that you can possibly be on after exactly this number of jumps.  A special treatment for small `N` does not seem to really give a lot of efficiency gain.  If you have a proof that `N` > 49 always has a solution, on the other hand, you should have a guard clause and a comment that outlines the proof.